# Update Map with list of changes efficently

Tags: java, optimization, dictionary, dart

Imagine a simple turn-based game; there are some players each with his own position:

```
Map<Player,ModelPosition> modelPositions
```

the GUI also has a similar map with pixel position

```
Map<Player,PixelPosition> guiPositions
```

Each turn a few players move. I compile a map of **only the players that moved that turn**:

```
Map<Player,ModelPosition> movements
```

Now I'd like to pass these movements to the gui to update the `PixelPosition` of the players that moved. Something like this:

```
for(Player p in movements.keySet())
{
 guiPositions[p] = modelToPixelConverter(movements[p]))
}
```

Now my problem is how to do it efficiently. I can make this slightly faster by looping over the Map.Entry (in Java) or using forEach (in Dart), but my real issue is that I am not iterating over guiPosition as well. I feel it wasteful to keep accessing it without iterating over it. Am I wrong?

Is there a way to do it in Java/Dart? I am also just interested in the general principle here.

Comment: I wonder why you don't use just one Position class whith two getters where one returns the pixel- and the other the model-position like `class Position { ModelPosition get modelPosition => ...; PixelPosition get pixelPosition }` then you don't need the loop at all.

Comment: mostly because view depends on html and so cannot be unit tested.